# Sorting a table in python

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a league table for a 6 a side football league and I am attempting to sort it by the points column and then display it in easygui. The code I have so far is this:

```
data = csv.reader(open('table.csv'), delimiter = ',')
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(7))
with open("Newtable.csv", "wb") as f:
          fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
          for row in sortedlist:
              fileWriter.writerow(row)
              os.remove("table.csv")
              os.rename("Newtable.csv", "table.csv")
              os.close
```

The number 7 relates to the points column in my csv file. I have a problem with Newtable only containing the teams information that has the highest points and the table.csv is apparently being used by another process and so cannot be removed.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this it would be appreciated.

Comment: I made these alterations and am still having an error in regards to table.csv being used by another process. And my sort is reversed with headings being at the bottom of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indentation in your post is actually the indentation in your script (and not a copy-paste error), then the problem is obvious:

`os.rename()` is executed during the `for` loop (which means that it's called once per line in the CSV file!), at a point in time where `Newtable.csv` is still open (not by a different process but by your script itself), so the operation fails.

You don't need to close `f`, by the way - the `with` statement takes care of that for you. What you *do* need to close is `data` - that file is also still open when the call occurs.

Finally, since a `csv` object contains strings, and strings are sorted alphabetically, not numerically (so `"10"` comes before `"2"`), you need to sort according to the numerical value of the string, not the string itself.

You probably want to do something like

```
with open('table.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    data = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = ',')
    sortedlist = [next(data)] + sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[7])) # or float?
    # next(data) reads the header before sorting the rest
with open("Newtable.csv", "wb") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    fileWriter.writerows(sortedList)          # No for loop needed :)
os.remove("table.csv")
os.rename("Newtable.csv", "table.csv")
```

Comment: I have altered this, but still get the error message about table.csv, as well as the newtable.csv being ordered in reverse

Comment: I have made a few adjustments; are the data really sorted in reverse, or is it just the header column that's "misplaced"? Are you aware that you're sorting strings, not numbers, so `"10"` sorts before `"2"`?

Comment: This did fix the initial processing problem with table.csv. But yes the data is now sorted in reverse, the points column is now ordered as so:
10
2
3
3
3
4
5
6
7
7

Comment: Is there any reason for writing to a different file and doing all this delete and rename operations? Why not just reopen the same for for writing?

Comment: @RafaelLerm: That's another (good) question. Well, at least if the script fails for some reason, the original file is not lost.

Comment: @TimPietzcker That is a good point. But I'd argue that not much run-time problems can happen at writing (except for a programming error), and recovery should be easy, since you have all the file contents in memory.

Comment: Apologies, I have only just seen the difference you made to the sortedlist section, after doing this the data is now ordered but in a descending order (2 at the top and 10 at the bottom). How do I alter this to be the other way around?

Comment: @RobertAvill: The `key` parameter determines the sorting order. So `lambda x: int(x[7])` will sort by ascending `x[7]`, and `lambda x: -int(x[7])` will sort by descending `x[7]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

Assuming an input file like this:

```
team,points
team1, 5
team2, 6
team3, 2
```

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('table.csv')
b=a.sort('points',ascending=False)
b.to_csv('table.csv',index=False)
```